# Some BigDecimal fail to calculate with ** operator

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

When I use `**` operator with negative `BigDecimal` and decimal `BigDecimal`, that fails with `Zero or negative argument` error.

I checked some similar values like this:

```
-2 ** '0.3'.to_d
# => -1.23114441
2 ** '0.3'.to_d
# => 1.23114441
2 ** '0.3'.to_d
# => 1.23114441
-2 ** '0.3'.to_d
# => -1.23114441
2.to_d ** '0.3'.to_d
# => 1.23114441
-2.to_d ** '0.3'.to_d
# => Math::DomainError: Zero or negative argument for log
from (pry):111:in `**'
2.to_d ** 3.to_d
# => 8.0
-2.to_d ** 3.to_d
# => -8.0
```

Why is this error happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand now what I have misunderstood.

I thought `-2.0 ** 0.3` is same as `(-2.0) ** 0.3`, but it is same as `-(2.0 ** 0.3)`.

I didn't know that `**` is stronger than `-`.

Comment: Whoa, that is *indeed* surprising.